# AngularJS directive scope binding not populated immediately in link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing the following directive:

```
.directive('mypagination', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            pageCount: "=",
        },
        template: "{{pageCount}}",
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.pages = [];
            for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.pageCount; i++) {
                $scope.pages.push(i);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

My issue is that `$scope.pageCount` inside the `for` loop is set to 0, but `{{pageCount}}` in the template is rendering the correct value.

In HTML the directive is being called like this:

```
<mypagination page-count="mjaController.pages.length" 
              on-page-change="mjaController.fetchStuff(page)">
</mypagination>
```

Why would the value of `pageCount` be 0 inside the `link` function, but render correctly on the page?

Comment: I tried with your code but seems coming correct value. can you check and console and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your `link` function is executed at that time `pageCount` can be `0` because it is bound to `mjaController.pages.length` property which I guess is retrieved from an API and is `async` call. Once the `mjaController.pages` is filled with some data, then `pageCount` is set to its length and is displayed on `template` via `$digest` cycle but `link` function will not execute again. To make it work as expected do following

```
.directive('mypagination', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            pageCount: "=",
        },
        template: "{{ pages()|json }}",
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.pages = function () {
              var pages = [];
              for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.pageCount; i++) {
                pages.push(i);
              }
              return pages;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

add a `method` in `$scope` and use its return value in template.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) to wait for the data to arrive from the server:

```
.directive('mypagination', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            pageCount: "<",
            onPageChange: "&"
        },
        template: "{{pageCount}}",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("pageCount", function(newValue) {
                if(newValue)
                    scope.pages = [];
                    for (var i = 1; i <= newValue; i++) {
                        scope.pages.push(i);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

In general, this type of data manupulation should be done in a directive's controller to take advantage of [life-cycle hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks) such as `$onChanges`. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based Application Architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture).